# Get call is showing MQ messages with few other chracters

Tags: ibm-mq, pymqi

I am writing simple program to read messages from MQ but looking few more other characters along with message.
The message is prefixed by "b" & appearing within quotes.

eg:
Message in MQ is:

```
{"vaultToken":"2223008965840750"}
```

After read its written in file as:

```
b'{"vaultToken":"2223008965840750"}'
```

Can you please let me know why it's happening? Is there any character conversion needed? ( It's happening with any sample message which i am inserting into MQ for test purpose.)

Below is the snippet of code:

```
qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info)

queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)
message = queue.get()
print(message)
```

Comment: I believe the 'b' means it is bytes. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: Thanks, this helps.